# (Mac  Terminal) sed to parse JSON ... what am I doing wrong?

Tags: sed, regular-expression, macos, json

In Mac Terminal, I'm trying to parse the "name" out of this JSON response:

> {"created_at":"2012-08-27T20:04:27Z","deleted_at":null,"id":21462840,"item_type":"video","name":"CastingBy-v12
>   mixed.mov","private":true,"redirect_url":null,"remote_url":"http://f.cl.ly/items/3D0P02b3e3p2I/CastingBy-v12%20mixed.mov","source":"Cloud/1.5.4
>   CFNetwork/520.4.3 Darwin/11.4.0 (x86_64)
>   (MacPro5%2C1)","updated_at":"2012-08-27T20:13:38Z","view_counter":2,"href":"http://my.cl.ly/items/2840","icon":"http://my.cld.me/images/item-types/video.png","subscribed":true,"url":"http://files.housenyc.com/1I3E2F3C","content_url":"http://files.eeehousenyc.com/1I3Q0Z1E2F3C/CastingBy-v12%20mixed.mov","download_url":"http://files.eeehousenyc.com/1I3Q0F3C/download/CastingBy-v12%20mixed.mov","gauge_id":null}

I'm using

`sed 's/{.*?"name":"\(.+?\)".*/\1/'`

but it returns the whole string.

I want it to return just

`CastingBy-v12 mixed.mov`

Comment: Can you use Python, instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the expression you are looking for:

```
sed -e 's/^.*"name":"\([^"]*\)".*$/\1/' infile
```

It results to:

```
CastingBy-v12 mixed.mov
```

In yours there are several errors:

- In `sed` only greeding expression can be used: `.*?` and `.+?` are incorrect.
- The `+` must be escaped.
- Use `[^"]*` to avoid that the regular expression matches until last
  double quotes of the string.

Comment: Thanks for all the tips! But that still returns the entire string. I'm using `echo "{my big string}" | sed 's/^.*"name":"\([^"]\+\)".*$/\1/'`

Comment: @Ze'ev: Sorry. It works for me and I cannot catch the issue that doesn't work for you.

Comment: Maybe because I'm on Mac using Terminal?

Comment: @zeev, Yes, Mac uses a BSD sed that doesn't have all the gnu features. I tested a bit and it seems Mac's sed doesn't recognize either `+` or `\+`.  Change that to `*` .

Comment: @Kevin AHA! That did it! Thanks! `| sed 's/^.*"name":"\([^"]*\)".*$/\1/'`

Comment: The sed expression will not work for numeric JSON attributes, so the fixed expression for both numeric and string attributes is 
    sed -e 's/^.*"name":["]?([^"}\]]*)["]?,.*$/\1/' infile

Answer (score 10):

Parsing json with just sed is as problematic as parsing HTML - in short: since elements can embed other elements and regex doesn't support recursion, it's essentially impossible to parse correctly with just regexp.

There's a PCRE solution to parsing and validating json here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2583472/regex-to-validate-json - I haven't used or tested it so I'll have to take the author's word that it works...*but* PCRE does a lot of things that just aren't in the basic or extended regexps supported by sed.

In any case, IMO you're better off using perl or python or awk and one of the json parsing libs for those languages, or a specialised json parsing tool - several are mentioned here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3858671/unix-command-line-json-parser

Any of them can be used to extract data from JSON input for use in a shell script.  Or you could write your entire program within that language.

For example, piping your json data into python -mjson.tool results in this:

```
$ echo "JSONDATAHERE" | python -m json.tool
{
    "content_url": "http://files.eeehousenyc.com/1I3Q0Z1E2F3C/CastingBy-v12%20mixed.mov", 
    "created_at": "2012-08-27T20:04:27Z", 
    "deleted_at": null, 
    "download_url": "http://files.eeehousenyc.com/1I3Q0F3C/download/CastingBy-v12%20mixed.mov", 
    "gauge_id": null, 
    "href": "http://my.cl.ly/items/2840", 
    "icon": "http://my.cld.me/images/item-types/video.png", 
    "id": 21462840, 
    "item_type": "video", 
    "name": "CastingBy-v12 mixed.mov", 
    "private": true, 
    "redirect_url": null, 
    "remote_url": "http://f.cl.ly/items/3D0P02b3e3p2I/CastingBy-v12%20mixed.mov", 
    "source": "Cloud/1.5.4 CFNetwork/520.4.3 Darwin/11.4.0 (x86_64) (MacPro5%2C1)", 
    "subscribed": true, 
    "updated_at": "2012-08-27T20:13:38Z", 
    "url": "http://files.housenyc.com/1I3E2F3C", 
    "view_counter": 2
}
```

which you can then pipe into sed like this:

```
$ echo "JSONDATAHERE" | python -m json.tool | sed -n -e '/"name":/ s/^.*"\(.*\)".*/\1/p'
CastingBy-v12 mixed.mov
```

Relying on the greedy nature of regexp, the sed script extracts everything between the second-last `"` and the last `"` character on any line containing `"name":`.

Comment: BTW, yes I *have* used regexps to parse HTML and JSON.  I've even made it work for my specific needs at the time...but I know that what I did was fragile and prone to failure and highly sensitive to the input data.  These days I usually find it easier and far more reliable to pre-process the json data with `python -m json.tool` and then pipe that into sed or awk.  or just write a perl script using the JSON module.  I'll still use regexps for a quick and dirty one-liner hack, but for anything intended to be used repeatedly, I'll do it properly.

Answer (score 3):

This dosn't answer your question directly. But if you need to do such things on a regular basis, consider using a generally available programming language like Perl, Python, Ruby.

In Ruby, your solution would be:

`some_command_that_emits_json | ruby -e "require 'rubygems';require 'json'; output=JSON.parse(STDIN.gets); puts output['name']"`

Answer (score 2):

Going from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1955505/parsing-json-with-sed-and-awk), this does the trick:

`echo {json...foo} | awk -F=":" -v RS="," '$1~/"name"/ {print}' | sed 's/\"//g' | sed 's/name://'`

Comment: You probably want `RS=","` to become `RS=",|{|}"`; in case what you are looking for is at the beginning or end of the line.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it with the `JSON` module of `perl`:

```
 json_producing_process | perl -MJSON -lne 'print from_json($_)->{name}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have `jq` available on your macOS system (e.g. by installing it via the Homebrew package manager):

```bsh
some_command | jq -r '.name'
```

... where `some_command` is a command producing your JSON document.  The `jq` command here extracts the value of the `name` key and decodes it (if needed).

Given your document in the question, this would produce a single line saying

```
CastingBy-v12 mixed.mov
```